# Change farm admin account in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, farm-admin

We would like to change the admin account of our SharePoint. This (one and only admin) account is currently SP Farm admin, SP server local admin, being used as application pool identity, being used to run services in SharePoint server. What are all the places we need to check to change from Admin account1 to Admin2 account? I was able to think of below, are there any other places we need to check?

- Application Pool Identities
- Accounts in SharePoint Admin and Timer services
- Owner permissions on SQL content data bases
- SharePoint Farm admin group
- SharePoint server local admin
- Search and other services in SP

Answer (score 3):

i will make sure I captured everything which is being run by farm admin account. To check, `go to Central admin > Security > Configure managed accounts > edit the farm account` Now on this page, look at the bottom (Account Information) for "Farm components using this account". This will tell you all the components using the farm credentials.

You have to make sure following

- new Farm account should have DBcreator and Security Admin on SQL servers
- Database owner permission on all Dbs(Config,Services,Content & central admin db).
- added into local admin as well as WSS_WPG & WSS_ADMIN_WPG groups.
- added in managed account
- if you have more than 1 server make sure you run the command on all servers

Answer (score 3):

In an elevated PowerShell command prompt:

```
stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin domain\account -password password
```

Or check the blog:
[Change the Farm Service Account in SharePoint 2013](http://tomislavspadmin.blogspot.sg/2014/06/change-farm-service-account-in.html)